# Is there a provision to invoke jamfile and jamrule from cmake and vice versa?

Tags: cmake, jam, cmake-language

Trying to migrate a legecy codebase whose buildsystem  jam to CMake.

to divide and conquer it , checking whether there and provisions  to Is there a provision to invoke jamfile and jamrule from cmake and vice versa .

one option would be add a custom target invoking jam program. 
is it also possible to use a jamrule defined in a jamfile / .jam file

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: There are several jam flavors. The answer applies to Perforce Jam and some of its compatible descendants.

As you've already mentioned yourself, invoking jam from cmake can be done with `add_custom_target`/`add_custom_command`, so that answers the first part of your question.

Since jam rules (or rather actions) can invoke arbitrary commands, the other direction is certainly possible as well. `cmake` itself is usually not the tool you invoke for building a target. So, depending on your generator, you would actually want to call `make`, `ninja`,...

In your question you're not very concrete regarding you migration approach. Assuming you start out with a jam build system with multiple library and executable targets that span a dependency graph, and you want to migrate the build system component by component. If you start bottom up with a library without dependencies (whose sources hopefully live in their own subdirectory), you would replace the rule invocation that builds the library -- e.g. `Library libfoo : foo.c bar.c ;` -- by a rule invocation that calls e.g. `make` -- like `Make libfoo$(SUFLIB) ;`. The rule could be defined (e.g. in `Jamrules`) as:

```
rule Make
{
    # tell jam where the target will be created
    MakeLocate $(1) : $(LOCATE_TARGET) ;

    # always invoke the actions, since we don't let jam check the target's dependencies
    Always $(1) ;

    # we need the source dir in the actions
    SOURCE_DIR on $(1) = $(SUBDIR) ;
}

actions Make
{
    # get absolute source dir path
    sourceDir=`cd $(SOURCE_DIR) && pwd`

    # cd into the output directory
    cd $(LOCATE)

    # generate Makefile, if not done yet
    if [ ! -e Makefile ]; then
        cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" $(sourceDir) ;
    fi

    # make the target
    make `basename $(1)`
}
```

If you need other information from jam to be passed to cmake (like the build type or certain build options), define respective on-target variables (like `SOURCE_DIR` in the example) to have them available in the actions.